# Test that fails if console.log() is contained in code

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

How would one write a unit test that fails if code contains any `console.log(x)` statements? Preferrably in Jest.

E.g.

```
// Do something
console.log(myVar)
// Do something
```

Result: Test fails because console.log(myVar) exists.

```
//Do something (no console.logs)
```

Result: Test passes because no console.logs exists.

Comment: Make `console.log` a mock function and `expect(log).not.toHaveBeenCalled()`?

Comment: Unit test? That is more of a linting check. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console

Comment: that's not a unit test and it shouldn't exist.